# How to rebuild the theme registry on every page?

Tags: 7, performance

I returned to Drupal 7 after a short absence, and couldn't find the option to "Rebuild the theme registry on every page", which is useful while editing templates on a development site. I thought it was in the Performance options but I can't find it there, and searching for it gives unclear or out of date results, mostly around the Zen theme which I haven't used for years. I've definitely used this setting without using Zen.

Where's the Drupal option to rebuid the theme registry on every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't included in stock Drupal 7.

If you're not using Zen, the most common way to access this feature is via the module [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel).

Then it's accessible from `/admin/config/development/devel`, right down the bottom of the page.